# Passing a object reference outside of handler, ie make it global

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

This is more of a best practices question I assume, but in the following, can anyone tell me how I would pass a reference of the socket object outside of the method handler it is in?

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
       console.log('connection '+socket);

//do stuff here

});//end callback handler

//need a reference to socket here!!
```

Comment: how do you intend to call the method which need the `socket`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign it to a variable defined in that scope?

```
var globalSocket;

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  globalSocket = socket;
});

// now what?
```

However, I don't see a reason to do this since you won't be able to use the value until the event handler was called (which you only know when the event handler was called).

To solve that, you would need to put the code that needs access to the socket in a function and call the function from the event handler:

```
var globalSocket;

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  globalSocket = socket;
  doSomething();
});

function doSomething() {
  // do something with globalSocket
  console.log(globalSocket);
}
```

but then it would be much more elegant to pass `socket` as argument to the function:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  doSomething(socket);
});

function doSomething(socket) {
  // do something with socket
  console.log(socket);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to store this in some sort of socket connection pool. But keep in mind that if you want to distribute in several process/machines with loadbalancers, this will not work very well.

Comment: OR assume I have just 1 socket connection?
var socket= io.socket;